# Get loop controller's current value

Tags: jmeter

I've made a Loop Controller to execute multiple time a sequence of instructions. But inside those sequences I need to get the current loop that I'am in so in my HTTP request I can make something like : path : website.com/${currentLoopValue}.

Is it possible to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be using [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element.

1. Add Counter as a child of your Loop Controller
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Counter Configuration]
3. You will be able to refer current loop iteration value as `${counter}` where required

   [image: JMeter Counter in action]

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) for more detailed information on generating incrementing values via aforementioned Counter test element and/or [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter)

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter inside the loop controller and access it using reference name of the counter
Refer http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter

Comment: And how's the counter is going to be linked in any way to the current loop value? And if I add a counter am I not just going to create another loop inside the controller's loop?

Comment: counter will be considered as a variable it wont create any loop, the counter will incremented on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

Use while controller instead.Please follow below steps.

1. create a user define variable(say **nTimesToRun**) ,which holds number of 
   times loop should be executed.

2.Create while controller.

3.create a counter which starts from 1 and increment by 1.Name that counter like "**myCounter**".And place all the requests which you want to loop.

4.The condition in while loop should look like "**${__javaScript("${myCounter}" != "${nTimesToRun}",)}**"

5.Use ${myCounter} where you want to replace in request.